# iOS - Show item lists from Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, alamofire

I am downloading data from SERVER_URL and saving to local database - Realm.
I am trying to show items on the list from this database, but I am getting an error. I am gonna be grateful for some tips.

```
Alamofire.request(SERVER_URL).responseJSON { response in

      let items = [Item].from(jsonArray: response.result.value as! [Gloss.JSON])
         print(items?[0] as Any)

        for item in items! {

            let itemRealm = ItemRealm()
            itemRealm.id = item.id!
            itemRealm.name = item.name!
            itemRealm.desc = item.descr!
            itemRealm.icon = item.icon!

            try! self.realm.write {
                self.realm.add(itemRealm)
            }
        }
    }

    let items = realm.objects(ItemRealm.self)
    print(items[0])
```

Error -> is directing me to class AppDelegate..... -> Thread1: signal SIGABRT

Console error log:

2017-02-01 16:51:20.701 iOSRecruitmentTest[15958:982747] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Index 0 is out of bounds (must be less than 0)'
*** First throw call stack:....  .
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `let items = realm.objects(ItemRealm.self)` is called before the `responseJSON` closure.

Don't forget that a network code *usually* runs asynchronously! Put your code inside the closure and it should be fixed.

On a side note, also try to limit the number of `realm.write` if you can, in this example you can achieve that easily by doing something like :

```
Alamofire.request(SERVER_URL).responseJSON { response in

  let items = [Item].from(jsonArray: response.result.value as! [Gloss.JSON])
     print(items?[0] as Any)

    // !! Only one write transaction
    try! self.realm.write {
        for item in items! {
            let itemRealm = ItemRealm()
            itemRealm.id = item.id!
            itemRealm.name = item.name!
            itemRealm.desc = item.descr!
            itemRealm.icon = item.icon!
            self.realm.add(itemRealm)
        }
    }

    // !! This code is now inside the closure
    let itemRealms = realm.objects(ItemRealm.self)
    print(itemRealms[0])
}
```

Comment: I had to transform let items = realm.objects(ItemRealm.self) into _ = self.realm.objects(ItemRealm.self) because I was getting error of Definition conflicts with previous value. This seems to work, however when I want to rerun the app again it gives me the same error as before, so I have to kill it and run fresh one. So it only works for the first time. Thanks for your input. Should I delete data somehow after closing?

Comment: I have edited my answer : as you don't want to print the json results, you want to print the realm object. I don't exactly know what you are trying to achieve, but if you have errors like this I'd encourage you to __safely unwrap the optionals__ and add some __error cases__. If the response is empty, with the actual code, the app will crash.

Comment: Okey, thank you. That is very helpful. I am doing some tests with simple list and usage Realm as database. I think the problem with the crash might be because I have put my network connection in viewDidLoad(). Correct me if I am wrong. Now I think by reading the error log: The data is saved, so when I rerun app it's downloaded again and the "id" = 0 is already there. That will explain the crash.

Comment: That could be an explanation. If you are downloading an update of an object, then you may be interested in *updating* the object instead of trying to *inserting* it to the realm database. You can achieve that by setting the *update* flag to *true* when adding an object. Example: ```realm.add(itemRealm, update: true)```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks again for your time and input in answering considering my issues.